# Sorting product Sort by category | WinterCMS/ OctoberCMS Plugin Builder

Tags: php, plugins, builder, octobercms

Another question from a noob.
On the page, I need to get a list of Categories with Subcategories something like:

- Category 1

  - Subcategory1_Category1
  - Subcategory2_Category1
- Category 2

  - Subcategory1_Category2
  - Subcategory2_Category 2

I have two models - Category and Subcategory.

I'm added relationship
Subcategory Model:

```
use \Winter\Storm\Database\Traits\SimpleTree;
public $belongsTo = [
        'category' => [
            'AName\PName\Models\Category',
            'key' => 'category_id']
    ];
```

Catalog Components:

```
$this->page['categories'] = Category::get();
$subcategories = $this->page['subcategories'] = Subcategory::where('category_id', $category->$id)->get();
```

I receive 'Undefined variable: category'
Where is the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach.

You need to define `sub_categories` relation in to your parent model `Category`

```php
// Category Model
public $hasMany = [
    'sub_categories' => AName\PName\Models\Subcategory
]
```

Now once you get the main categories you can retrieve its sub-category by just calling `sub_categories` relation

> In code section

```php
$this->page['categories'] = Category::get();
```

> In markup section

```
{% for category in categories %}
    - {{ category.title }}
    {% for subCategory in category.sub_categories %}
        -- {{ subCategory.title }}        
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: May the saints protect you, you saved my life! :) It really works!